# Использование Stream API для списка

Tags: java, api, потоки-данных

подскажите решение следующей задачи, имеется список

```
TreeList<String[]>mans
```

каким образом используя Striam API можно создать список

```
TreeList<String>name
```

куда поместить все первые элементы массивов входящих в список mans? Я понимаю что можно просто пройтись циклом, но ищу решение с помощью Stream API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ArrayList(Суть та же):

```
ArrayList<String[]> mans = new ArrayList<>();
mans.add(new String[] {"1hi", "", "2hi", "", "3hi"});
mans.add(new String[] {"4hi", "5hi", "6hi"});

mans.stream()
    .map(a -> {
        StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder("");
        for(String string : a) {
            if(!string.isEmpty()) {
                toReturn.append(string.substring(0, 1));
            }
        }
        return toReturn.toString();
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Оптимизированный вариант:

```
mans.stream()
    .map(a -> {
        char[] firstChars = new char[a.length];
        int countOfEmpty = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < firstChars.length - countOfEmpty; i++) {
            if(!a[i + countOfEmpty].isEmpty()) {
                firstChars[i] = a[i + countOfEmpty].charAt(0);
            } else {
                i--;
                countOfEmpty++;
            }
        }
        return new String(firstChars).substring(0, firstChars.length - countOfEmpty);
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Оба выводят следующее:

> 123
>   456

А собрать в один список вы можете заменив forEach() на collect(), в котором можно преобразовать поток строк в нужную вам коллекцию